# MATLAB: Extracting x coordinate that matches up with largest y value

Tags: matlab, csv, plot, coordinates, figure

Using matlab to extract values from a csv file, doing an fft transform on part of the data and then plotting it. In looking at the plot, I see a clear peak (see figure attached) and am wanting to write something to extract the x coordinate of the peak.

Here is the part of the code I wrote.

```
   filename=input('Enter name of a csv file, extension included : ', 's');
csv_file=load(filename);

%file_rows
rows = size(csv_file, 1);

for i = 1:rows-256   %frames
rh_x= csv_file(i:i+255,60); % coordinates of joint 1
rh_y= csv_file(i:i+255,61);

rh_x2 = csv_file(i:i+255, 12); % coordinates of joint 2
rh_y2 = csv_file(i:i+255, 13);

coord = [rh_x, rh_y; rh_x2, rh_y2];

distarray = sqrt( (rh_x + rh_x2).^2 + (rh_y + rh_y2).^2 ); %distance formula
meandist = mean(distarray);

new_arr = distarray - meandist;  %subtract mean

transf_new = fft(new_arr);  %FFT transform
magn_new = abs(transf_new);  %magnitude_output


plot(magn_new(1:size(magn_new,1)/2), '-');  %****I INCLUDED EVERYTHING BUT THIS IS THE PART THAT PLOTS WHAT I WANT TO EXTRACT FROM

 if i==1
        hold on
 end
end
```

The code gives me all the right values I need, I just now want to extract the x value of the very obvious peak in this figure (this figure was generated using one of my CSV files). **How can I write something that will store/display the x coordinate of that peak I generate?**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: if you just want the position in x of the maximum point use `[val ind]=max(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the two-output syntax of `max`:

> `[Y,I] = max(X)` returns the indices of the maximum values in vector I.
>      If the values along the first non-singleton dimension contain more
>      than one maximal element, the index of the first one is returned.

So for a given array `magn_new(1:size(magn_new,1)/2)`,

```
[maxval, imax] = max(magn_new(1:size(magn_new,1)/2));
```

`maxval` will then contain the maximal `y` value, and `imax` will contain the corresponding *index* (which in your case happens to be the `x` coordinate, since you're implicitly plotting versus `1:size(magn_new,1)/2`.

Since you're generating your data batch by batch, you can store each `imax` and `maxval` for each batch, or just check each time whether the new `maxval` is larger than the previous largest `maxval`, and if yes, then overwrite `imax`.